# How to filter pivot tables by a cell value in wkst 1 with the pivot tables on Wkst 2.How can i modify my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently filtering pivot tables by a cell value in worksheet 1 and that works great. However, i will be moving the pivot tables to Worksheet 2 and keeping only the charts for each table on worksheet 1. I want to continue using the cell value from worksheet 1 to filter. I'm constructing my dash board on worksheet 1. How can i modify my code and suggestions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim NewCat As String

    'if this is in the sheet1 code module you can use
    '  "Me" in place of "Worksheets("Sheet1")"
    NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Value
    Debug.Print "Filtering on '" & NewCat & "'"
    'loop over all pivottables on the sheet
    For Each pt In Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
        With pt.PivotFields("Customer Name")
           .ClearAllFilters
            .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=NewCat
        End With
    Next pt

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you just posted has everything you just asked for. It just needs to be edited a bit. I suggest you read an introduction to VBA guide online. There should be hundreds of free ones. Excel Easy is a good start. Once you know what every line does on the code you put here, it will be very very easy to change it to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the question is when do you want the code to be triggered? Currently, it is ran once there is an event "SelectionChange" in the worksheet. I guess, the idea is that it should be triggered once a change is done in the pivot data. Thus, this code should be written in `Sheet2`:

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim NewCat As String

    NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H3").Value
    For Each pt In Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables
        With pt.PivotFields("Customer Name")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=NewCat
        End With
    Next pt

End Sub
```

In order to make the code working with amongst all the worksheets by just copying and pasting it, consider changing `Worksheets("Sheet2")` with `Me` everywhere. Thus, the `Me` is referring to the code worksheet in which it resides. In the case above `Me = Worksheets("Sheets2")`.

Comment: Thank you great stuff!! Very wise!

Comment: @OscarIracheta - glad I could help. [You may consider marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)